# Authentication Login

Tags: android

I am developing a app as we can see with some apps that you can login using that account as for example 
while signing on quora there are options to sign in using either google or facebook.
I want to sign in my user using samsung account.
Please Help!!

Answer (score 0):

They don't provide the API related to Samsung Account in public.

http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SDK&messageId=244247

Comment: @sharma Ny  option left then?